# Print both the duplicate values name from the nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
students=[['Ash',85.25],['Kai',85.25],['Ray',75],['Jay',55.5]]

output:Ash
       Kai
```

I'm trying to solve a task and i'm new in python.I am not getting what i want can anyone explain me how one can do it

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to group the values into a [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>>
>>> students = [['Ash',85.25],['Kai',85.25],['Ray',75],['Jay',55.5]]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for value, key in students:
...     d[key].append(value)
... 
>>> for value in d.itervalues():
...     if len(value) > 1:
...         print(value)
... 
['Ash', 'Kai']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that:

```
students = [['Ash', 85.25], ['Kai', 85.25], ['Ray', 75], ['Jay', 55.5]]

common_names = []
for i, i_x in enumerate(students):
    for i_y in students[:i] + students[i + 1:]:
        if i_x[1] == i_y[1]:
            common_names.append(i_x[0])

print(common_names)
#['Ash', 'Kai']

# or if you want it to print every entry in a single line:
print('\n'.join(x for x in common_names))
#Ash
#kai
```

Explain:

1. I grab an object from the original list `students`. Object is `i_x` and its `['Ash', 85.25]` on the first iteration for example.
2. Then i slice the list `students[:i] + students[i + 1:]` to create another one in memory that contains all the elements of the original one apart from `i_x`
3. I check to see if there is any item in the newly created list that has the same `[1]` index value as that of `i_x`. If yes, i append the `i_x[0]` value to a third list that holds the results.
4. I do this for as many elements as there are originally in the `students` list.

---

**Can anybody provide a list comprehension for the above?**

Comment: Is not it of an O(n^2) (n-squared) complexity? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe i do not understand why this: `print([x[0] for y in (students[:i] + students[i + 1:]) for i, x in enumerate(students) if x[1] == y[1]])` does not work..